# Sum cells from columns except columns to left in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm experimenting with pandas dataframe and would like change below:

```
Weeks            1       2       3      4      5   
CohortMonth                                                                 
2020-01-01    483.0  1064.0   590.0  323.0  211.0  
2020-02-01    ... 
2020-03-01    ...
```

It want to add up above numbers so first column is the total of all columns, 2nd the total of all columns except first, etc. Example:

```
Weeks            1       2       3      4      5   
CohortMonth                                                                 
2020-01-01    2671.0  2188.0  1124.0 534.0  211.0  
2020-02-01    ... 
2020-03-01    ...
```

last snippet of code before it creates the table:

```
cohort_data = df1.groupby(['CohortMonth', 'Weeks'])['UserID'].apply(pd.Series.nunique).reset_index()
cohort_count = cohort_data.pivot_table(index='CohortMonth',
                                       columns='Weeks',
                                       values='UserID')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this using `cumsum()` but using `df[::-1]`. This will work irrespective of the number of columns you have. It will sum as many columns as you have as long as those columns are numbers and can be summed.

Here's the implementation.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weeks':['2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-03-01','2020-04-01'],
                  '1':[11,12,13,14],
                  '2':[15,16,17,18],
                  '3':[19,20,21,22],
                  '4':[23,24,25,26],
                  '5':[27,28,29,30]})

#first copy all the columns except the first one into another dataframe
#we need to exclude the fisrt column as we cannot calculate on first column
dT = df.loc[:,df.columns != 'Weeks']

#use cumsum to calculate the values in reverse order
dT = dT[dT.columns[::-1]].cumsum(axis=1)[dT.columns]

#add back the first column to the dataframe
dT.insert (0, "Weeks", df['Weeks'])

#original dataframe
print (df)

#reverse order cumulative DataFrame
print (dT)
```

Original Dataframe :

```
        Weeks   1   2   3   4   5
0  2020-01-01  11  15  19  23  27
1  2020-02-01  12  16  20  24  28
2  2020-03-01  13  17  21  25  29
3  2020-04-01  14  18  22  26  30
```

Reverse Cumulative Dataframe

```
        Weeks    1   2   3   4   5
0  2020-01-01   95  84  69  50  27
1  2020-02-01  100  88  72  52  28
2  2020-03-01  105  92  75  54  29
3  2020-04-01  110  96  78  56  30
```

Comment: This solution worked best for me! I skipped `dT.insert (0, "Weeks", df['Weeks'])`

Comment: Thanks. If this helped, please feel free to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function to do the `sum` of the specified columns and return a `pd.Series` object for each column.

```
def sumof(x):
    weeks = {}
    weeks['1'] = x[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']].sum(axis=1)[1]
    weeks['2'] = x[['2', '3', '4', '5']].sum(axis=1)[1]
    weeks['3'] = x[['3', '4', '5']].sum(axis=1)[1]
    weeks['4'] = x[['4', '5']].sum(axis=1)[1]
    weeks['5'] = x['5'][1]

    return pd.Series(weeks)
```

Then we can `groupby` weeks in the `df` and apply the function to those groups

```
result = df.groupby('Weeks').apply(sumof)

                 1       2       3      4      5
Weeks                                           
2020-01-01  2671.0  2188.0  1124.0  534.0  211.0
```

This requires all columns are `dtype` `int` or `float` otherwise it will ignore the value in that column.